# When does a family become a wizard family?

Tags: harry-potter

NB: This isn't a question about degrees of bloodlines (as signified by the "m" word).

The Grangers produced 1 child with magic ability, are they a wizard family? 
The Evans' produced 1 child with and 1 without magic ability, are they a wizard family? 
(I believe both of these sets of parents have no magic ability, I can't find anything to the contrary.)
Lily & James Potter produced 1 child with magic ability, and had magic themselves. Were James Potter's parents magic users?

Is it definitely stated that a wizard family must have 2 magic parents?

Comment: Are you asking about terminology used in-universe? Or "wizard" as in magical ability?

Comment: Little known JKR footnote: When a male wizard and a female wizard love each other, she takes his wand and...conjures up a wizard family. In the case of a wizard/muggle union, it's just a wizard's family until a magic user is born. In the muggle/muggle with a wizard offspring situation, Mom has been hanging out at the Leaky Cauldron while Dad's been on a roadtrip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking what makes someone being able to be called "Wizard family".

Problem with that question is: *By whose definition?*

- People who typically care to operate with the term "wizard family" would likely be be blood purists, for whom the answer is "wizards as ancestors in all generations forever" (as we are told by Ron, incorrectly - most pureblood families have muggles somewhere in the tree).
- Colloquially, someone might refer to "Wizarding family" as someone whose children grow up steeped in Wizarding world (e.g. it doesn't matter if one of the parents is a Muggle, as long as a child grows up **as a** Wizard)

  In linguistic terms, it can be thought of as a loose equivalent of "Army brat" expression.

  In addition, even if the parents are both muggle-born, they would still be a Wizarding family if they raise their child in wizarding world (if, Harry was 100% muggle born, and - be still, shippers! - married Hermione, their children would grow up in Wizarding family).
- Another usage may be to merely reflect a wizarding family line (e.g. no emphasis on blood purity per se, merely "here's a tree of ancestors some of whom were wizard, and share last name), e.g. Weasleys.

JKR herself doesn't give a formal definition of what SHE as an author considers "wizard family".

Comment: Yes, your comment "by whose definition" makes it clear that the answer to this question must always depend on the person asking. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would say that it depends a lot on your expectations of a wizard family.  For example, if you take a Canadian couple that migrates to the UK and have a child there; are they now a British family?  If they have no child or have one or more before departure and remains after that in the UK for 20, 30 years or more; are they still a Canadian family after all this time; weither or not that they have any new child there?

I would say that the knowledge of the wizard world is important in the definition of a wizard family and therefore, that any family with a least one magical member and a knowledge of the wizardly world should be considered as a wizard family.  However, this is only my personal view and I perfectly understand that many other peoples won't be OK with that.

Comment: Thank you - by this reasoning you could almost say the Dursleys are a magical family! I guess they wouldn't be very happy about this!

Comment: The Dursleys know about magic; therefore, you can/should consider them more of a magical family than the other families on their street.  You just also take into consideration what to say about a family with no magical parents but with many magical childs; say for example 10 childs.  Would you say that such a family shouldn't be considered as a magical family?  In the end, you decide where to put the line but never forget that the Dursleys know more about magic than a lot of pure non-magical family.